# absolute position element to inherit all the style of parent

Tags: html, css, absolute

> I figured it out why inherit did not work, lets say parent container width is 20% of body, and if i say inherit that width, so that's means child will 20% of 20%, so i know why it did not work, now my question is can i force my absolute positing element to inherit all the style from parent.

i am trying to create drop down menu two level, than as usual i got confused, cause as soon as i gave absolute positing to my drop down, they did not inherit style from parent container. 
I was kinda confuse by this point, so i use the inherit value for width and for background; for background it work but not for the width it did not; than i got more confused, so i decided to post it here.

My question is why width 100% work and not inherit, 
and my another question is how can i force my absolute positing div to inherit all the style from the parent,

in short i am fine with it's getting out of normal flow but i don't want it to act like an orphan.

> Please read comment in the css code

**HTML CODE**

```
<ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

            <li class="menu2 has-drop-down"><a href="#">Services</a>
                <ul class="drop-down-1">
                    <li><a href="#">Plumbing</a></li>
                    <li class="has-drop-down"><a href="#">Heating</a>
                        <ul class="drop-down-2">
                            <li><a href="#">Residential</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Electrical</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Electrical</a></li> 

        </ul>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
 /*basic style no need to pay attention*/
 *{
    font-family:helvetica;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:20px;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;

}

.menu{  
    display:flex;
}
.menu >li{
    flex:1;
    background:red;
    margin-left:1px;
}
.menu2{
    position:relative;
}

/*This style is confusing as, as soon as i give this position 
absolute, my drop down width is not equal to its container,
it is not inheriting background color and no width either, 
### I think it's all come to down to absolute positioning 
will take your element out of normal flow###
*/
.drop-down-1{
    position:absolute;
    width:inherit;/*width:100% will work why?*/
    background:inherit;
}
.drop-down-2{
    position:absolute;
    width:inherit;/*width:100% will work why?*/
    background:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

background-color:inherit !important;

Comment: I changed it, sorry my mistake!

Comment: sorry for the let response, i just check your answer, If you read my question, you will realize that background:inherit work just fine, so why i should use !importance, thanks for the help,

Answer (score 0):

your using inherit property but there is no width property in the parent elements add width 100% to your parent menu2 class to make it work

```css
/*basic style no need to pay attention*/
 *{
    font-family:helvetica;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:20px;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;

}

.menu{  
    display:flex;
}
.menu >li{
    flex:1;
    background:red;
    margin-left:1px;
}
.menu2{
    position:relative;
width:100%;
}

/*This style is confusing as, as soon as i give this position 
absolute, my drop down width is not equal to its container,
it is not inheriting background color and no width either, 
### I think it's all come to down to absolute positioning 
will take your element out of normal flow###
*/
.drop-down-1{
    position:absolute;
    width:inherit;/*width:100% will work why?*/
    background:inherit;
}
.drop-down-2{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;/*width:100% will work why?*/
    background:inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

            <li class="menu2 has-drop-down"><a href="#">Services</a>
                <ul class="drop-down-1">
                    <li><a href="#">Plumbing</a></li>
                    <li class="has-drop-down"><a href="#">Heating</a>
                        <ul class="drop-down-2">
                            <li><a href="#">Residential</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Electrical</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Electrical</a></li> 

        </ul>
```

Comment: i am giving the width, i am using flex 1